# Prolog - Update a value in list of list

Tags: prolog

I have a fact :

```
available_resources([[r1, 0], [r2, 0]]).
```

I need when a specified condition is true increase the zero by 1 . like:

```
release(X):-
        allocated(X , R1):-
        increase r1 by one
```

I don't know how to update a fact.

Comment: You cannot update a value in a list. You need to create another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about "changeable state". As in functional languages (i.e. LISP et al.), this is harder to come by in Prolog! (For a functional view in the context of Clojure, see [Values and Change: Clojure’s approach to Identity and State](https://clojure.org/about/state))

What you can do is have a specific value for "time". Then you can have facts in the [Prolog database](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=db) like these:

```
available_resources(10, [this, and, that]).
available_resources(20, [hither, and, yon]).
```

Here we state that at time 10, the resources were `[this, and, that]`, and at time 20, the resources were `[hither, and, yon]`.

Then you can use [assertz](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=assertz/1) to add facts to the database and [retract](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=retract/1) to remove old ones.

```
release(X) :- available_resources(Tprev, Rprev),
              compute_new_resource_term(X,Rprev,Rcur),
              % get current time from an extralogical oracle              
              get_time(Tcur), 
              retract(available_resources(Tprev, Rprev)),
              assertz(available_resources(Tcur,Rcur)).
```

But if you do not need to have the "resources" term survive across program runs (i.e. through a return to the toplevel), you wuld just construct new terms and hand them from predicate to predicate without storing them in the database.